# Force production slot of an Azure web app to be always on

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a web app hosted on Azure that has three slots :

> 1 - Warmup
>  2 - Stage
>  3 - Production

Each slot as a property `AlwayOn` that is set to `True`.
I initially deploy the app on the warmup slot and then auto swap it to the stage slot.
Then I want to manually swap from stage to production but I have a warning saying `AlwaysOn` will be set to `False` after swap.

Why this setting is not specific to each slot ? Where can I set a property or something that will prevent the swap between two slots with `AlwaysOn` set to `True` to set the `AlwaysOn` in the destination slot to `False` ?

Answer (score 1):

If both the source and target slots of the swap have 'Always On' enabled, then both slots should continue to have it enabled after that swap.

Have you tried doing the swap to check whether it is preserved?

The warning seems odd. Can you show the details of what it looks like?

Comment: I tried to swap and production slot turn AlwaysOn to False. At the moment I can't reproduce this issue so it seems to be a temporary issue. Thanks.

Comment: My only explanation is that when it happened, staging slot somehow had the setting disabled.